# Java class not working

Tags: java, android, class, timertask

I want the code shown here to run all the time:

```
class secondClass extends TimerTask {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    public void onCreate(Context context) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.flyinghome);
    }

    public void run() {
        float x = (float) Math.random();
        float y = (float) Math.random();
        mp.setVolume(x, y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        secondClass task = new secondClass();  
        Timer timer = new Timer();          
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 2000);           
    }  
}
```

How can I have this `TimerTask` running a the same time as the MainActivity class if The MainActivity class extends Activity and implements OnCLickListener.

Comment: I am not familiar with threads, I shall look for some lessons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

> Each timer has one thread on which tasks are executed sequentially.

You can schedule a task to run inside that thread, using one of the schedulling functions, such as:

```
Timer t = new Timer();

t.schedule(new secondClass(), delay);
//delay is the amount of time in milliseconds before execution.
```

since you want it to run all the time, you can consider to use [schedule(java.util.TimerTask, long, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) that schedules a task for repeated fixed-delay execution after a specific delay.

```
Timer t = new Timer();

t.schedule(new secondClass(),  delay,period);
//delay is the amount of time in milliseconds before execution.
//period    amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.
```

An advice: i would change the class name to SecondClass, since the class names use to be capitaliced.

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly should this function be written? Inside which class / method?

Comment: wherever you want to start the second thread. in oncreate could be good

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using an Android service.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html